# How to synchronize my webapplication to my database?

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have got a Java Webapplication and I'm accessing an Oracle 11g database via JPA2 (EclipseLink)

Now had to make some changes in the stored data, but my Application is still caching the old values.

**Question:** How may I force my application to drop the whole cache and reload the data from the database (while the application is running)?

I have tried the following, but there seems to be no effect:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class CacheEvictall implements Serializable {
    // (...)

    public void evictDatabaseCache() {
        // clear persistence cache
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        if (em != null) {
            LOGGER.info("Evicting database cache!");
            try {
                utx.begin();
                emf.getCache().evict(FooClass.class);
                emf.getCache().evict(BarClass.class);
                // or: emf.getCache().evictAll();
                em.flush();
                utx.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "No EntityManager! Cannot evict cache!");
        }
    }
}
```

I even restarted the Application Server (Glassfish v3.1.2) and redeployed the application itself, but the same effect: nothing happens.

Thank you in advance
Fant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

evict will invalidate the cache and ensure the next query returns data from the database.

If you restart you application server, and still don't see the changes, then my guess is you are not changing the data.  Check if you committed the transaction, and check that you are updating the correct database.  Also ensure you are not dropping and recreating the table on start-up.